# Store: Removing item from cart triggers paid=yes

Tags: expresso-store, checkout

When removing an item from the cart in Store, I'm seeing the order being changed to Paid=Yes in Orders. It correctly stays as Incomplete status and doesn't show any items in the details, but Paid is Yes.

Removing works correctly otherwise, and am using:

```
<button class="cart-remove-btn" type="submit" name="remove_items[{key}]" value="x">x</button>
```

within the Store checkout form.

---

EE 2.9.2, Store version: 2.4.1

1 simple custom Store extension: uses on_store_order_complete_end to update Entry status

Comment: it is always best to add details such as the version of Store & EE you are using, if you are using any extensions to extend Store and relevant template code.

Comment: That would make sense! updated. Can add pared down full template if necessary.

Comment: Can you disable the extension to test to see if the order is still being marked as Paid=Yes when you remove items from the cart?

Comment: Yes, still paid=yes with the extension disabled.

Comment: I've tried paring down to nothing, and every parameter variation I can think, and custom extensions disabled, but same result. Also tried it with store_example template (removing qty from cart) and same thing.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this in our environments. Will respond to your ticket, but I think something else is going on here.